# Finding level curve for $\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm having trouble finding a level curve for the function f(x,y) = xy/(x^2 + y^2). 
I understand the general premise behind finding level curves, but with this function I can't figure out a way to manipulate it into that of an obvious 2D shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a=0$, then $\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}=a$ if and only if $(x=0\lor y=0)\land(x\ne 0\lor y\ne 0)$, therefore the level set is two lines minus their intersection points.

If $a\ne 0$, the the equation becomes $\begin{cases}x^2-\frac1axy+y^2=0\\ (x,y)\ne (0,0)\end{cases}$, which requires some additional cases.

If $1-4a^2\ge 0$ and $a\ne0$, then $$x^2-\frac1axy+y^2=\left(x-\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4a^2}}{2a}y\right)\left(x-\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4a^2}}{2a}y\right)$$

so that the level set is two lines minus their intersection (the origin) if $1-4a^2>0$, and one line minus the origin if $1-4a^2=0$.

If $1-4a^2<0$, then $$x^2-\frac1axy+y^2=\left(x-\frac y{2a}\right)^2+\frac{4a^2-1}{4a^2}y^2$$ so that the level set ends up being the empty set (because the polynomial is $0$ only for $x=y=0$).